# OpenGL ES 2.0: Performance drop using bindbuffer frequently

Tags: android, performance, opengl-es-2.0, frame-rate

I have a performance problem in my opengl 2.0 game. Framerate was good until I made a change in the game. Its some sort of outbreak game with 64 shapes (bricks). What I now want is when the ball hits a brick its not immediately removed - it changes status and that includes changing the texture or more correctly - the uv-coord of the atlas. I have a textureatlas and what I do is just to call GLES20.bindBuffer() for every texture in the loop, instead of calling the outside the loop. Earlier I had the same uv-coord for all shapes but now I change it depending on the bricks status and thats why I need to use binding inside the loop

```
 private void drawShape() {


    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboDataListLevelSprites.get(iName).getBuff_id_vertices());
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);


    //used this snipped before when using the same image (uv-coords) for all bricks
    /*GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboDataListLevelSprites.get(iName).getBuff_id_uvs());
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mTextureCoordinateHandle);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mTextureCoordinateHandle, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    */

    for (Iterator<BrickProperties> it = arrayListBricks.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {



        BrickProperties bp = it.next();
        //now bindbuffer inside loop just too switch uv-coords of the atlas when its time to use another image 
        int buffIndexVal = bp.get_status_diff();
        GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, BrickProperties.get_buff_id_uvs()[buffIndexVal]);
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mTextureCoordinateHandle);
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mTextureCoordinateHandle, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);


        Matrix.setIdentityM(mModelMatrix, 0);
        Matrix.translateM(mModelMatrix, 0, bp.getTranslateData()[0], bp.getTranslateData()[1], bp.getTranslateData()[2]);

        if (bp.get_status() == 0) {
            it.remove();
        }

        render();
    }
} 


private void render() {

    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mViewMatrix, 0, mModelMatrix, 0);
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVMatrixHandle, 1, false, mMVPMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjectionMatrix, 0, mMVPMatrix, 0);
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mMVPMatrix, 0);
    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
}
```

I understand the reason to the performance drop is all the bindbuffer calls to the GPU but how could I possibly get around this problem?

Answer (score 1):

It is one thing that you are binding a buffer for every object but then there is another thing you are using 2 buffers to draw a single object. You also have redundant call to unbind the buffer at the start of your `render` method, simply remove that.

In most cases (may be all cases) you want interleaved vertex data for increased performance. So use

```
{
   position,
   textureCoordinates
}
```

in a single buffer.

I see in your case you have 2 states of the same object where the second one will change vertex coordinates but not position coordinates. It might make sense to share the position data between the two if the buffer is relatively large (which I assume is not). Anyway for such sharing I would suggest you rather use your buffer structure as

```
{
   position,
   textureCoordinates,
   secondaryTextureCoordinates
}
```

then use a separate buffer or even to put the secondary texture coordinates to another part of the same buffer.

So if the vertex buffers are relatively small then I suggest you to use "atlas" procedure. For your case that would mean creating twice the size of the buffer and put all the coordinates (having position duplicated) and put this vertex data so that there is one part after another.

I assume you can easily do that for your current drawing and effectively reduce the number of bound buffers to 0 per draw call (you only ned to bind it at some initialization). Now you will have the second part where you will set the attribute pointers for each of the drawn element just so that you may control which texture coordinates are used. This will again present redundant calls which may be avoided in your case:

Since the data structure is consistent in your buffer there is really no reason to set the pointers more the once. Simply set them once to the beginning when buffer is bound and then use the offset in draw call to control what part of the buffer is actually used `GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, offset, 6)`.

If done properly your draw method should looks something like:

```
for (Iterator<BrickProperties> it = arrayListBricks.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
    BrickProperties bp = it.next();

    Matrix.setIdentityM(mModelMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.translateM(mModelMatrix, 0, bp.getTranslateData()[0], bp.getTranslateData()[1], bp.getTranslateData()[2]);

    if (bp.get_status() == 0) {
        it.remove();
    }

    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mViewMatrix, 0, mModelMatrix, 0);
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVMatrixHandle, 1, false, mMVPMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjectionMatrix, 0, mMVPMatrix, 0);
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mMVPMatrix, 0);
    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, bp.vertexOffset, 6);
}
```

This removes all the bindings and preserves only matrix operations and draw calls. If there are other drawings in the pipeline you need the buffer binding before the loop otherwise you may put it as a part of the initialization. In both cases the calls should be reduced significantly.

To add a note here it is a common practice to have another object that tracks the openGL states to avoid redundant calls. Instead of calling `GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferID..` you would rather call something like `contextObject.bindVertexBuffer(bufferID)` which would check if the `bufferID` is the same as in previous call. And if it is then no actual binding would be done. If you create and use such system then it makes little difference on where you call the buffer binding and rest of the object setup since redundant calls will have no effect. Still this procedure alone will not make your situation optimal so you still need both.

Comment: Thanks - I'll look into this more. I think I catch the problem

Answer (score 1):

You could bind buffer and draw all the objects with the same UV-s at once. Instead of iterating through each brick, iterate through all objects that use the same UV-s.

Also, try batching the objects so that you draw them all at once. Using Index Buffer Objects may help in this.